# Storing Grain in a Hot Garage?

Tags: storage, grain

I currently have my grain in air tight containers that I store inside. I would like to move them out to the garage which gets very hot. (100 degree summer days are common).

**Will the heat negatively effect the storage of the grain?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grain, and foodstuffs in general should be stored in a cool, dry area, since the warm temperature can increase the rate of staling. It depends upon how long the grain will be around for. If you can use it up within 6 months then I doubt you would notice much change, especially if it's stored in a sealed container.